# What do I do wrong here? Python Conditions

Tags: python

It says that apparently there is a mistake. I am very novice, and i really cant see what do i do wrong

````
print(age) 
if age>=18 
print("you may enter the site") 
elif print("no access")```
````

Comment: at least in your question, you have an extra ' before 18, and you're missing the code indentation after the if. But it may be only the way it's displayed here !?

Comment: If you edit the error message into your question by using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58828032/edit) helping you would be much easier. If you don't assign a value to your `age`-variable anywhere else this will be a problem. Also if this is your real indentation, that will be a problem as well. And last but not least a colon is missing after your `if`-statement.

Comment: Please return to your instructional materials to learn basic Python syntax.  "It says there is a mistake" is not a problem specification -- also review [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0):

First

Are you setting age as a variable somewhere else? Where is age coming from? you can't print what doesn't exist.

Second 
    if age >= '18

Are you looking at a number or a string? I'd assume you mean 18. '18' and 18 are not the same thing. One is a string of characters, the other is an integer. You also didn't terminate the string with a ' at the end.

Your if statement isn't properly formatted. Python is white space sensitive. Syntax for if is below.

```
if age >= 19:
    print("Something")
else:
    print("something else")
```